# Grouping and display line totals

Tags: crystal-reports

What I have is a vendor performance report and I have a column that calculates early/late days,

Example:
-7
22
3
-14
2
-1

I need a formula that will tell me how many line where 
1 to 7 days early
8 to 14 days early
+15 days
And also opposite how many days where late in the same format.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would probably want to use a running total for this to count the fields for each category. You should be able to create a running total that evaluates using a formula which will specify you date range.

Below is an example of the formula for one of the running total fields you could create:

```
{Vendors;1.vendor_dt} > CurrentDate //this is for the "late" category
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like you'd want to do a few COUNT() queries.  (Assuming you're using SQL.)

Comment: We are using a program called Epicor which runs SQL, Do you have any example i am very new to this.